# Error while running Dyanamo DB and creating AWS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have defined an IAM policy for Dynamodb cloud formation template as shown below, and I am getting the following error:

> Value of property Users must be of type List of String

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
myDynamoPolicy:
   Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
   Properties: 
     PolicyDocument:
       Version: 2012-10-17
       Statement:
         Sid: AllAPIActionsOnBooks
         Effect: Allow
         Action: dynamodb:*
         Resource: 
           Ref: myDynamoDBTable
     PolicyName: DynamoDBOwnerPolicy
     Users:
        Ref: IAMUsers
```

Answer (score 1):

Per AWS documentation, the `Users` property must be an array. It should look like this:

```
myDynamoPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
  Properties: 
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        Sid: AllAPIActionsOnBooks
        Effect: Allow
        Action: dynamodb:*
        Resource: 
          Ref: myDynamoDBTable
    PolicyName: DynamoDBOwnerPolicy
    Users:
      -
        Ref: "IAMUsers"
```

CloudFormation template reference can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-users).